# Determining in the bytecode where is the super() method call all constructors must do on the JVM

Tags: java, bytecode

I was wondering if there's an obvious and quick way of when analyzing a constructor's bytecode, to determine where the `super()` code ends in.

More concretely, and in sharp contrast to Java, where a call in the constructor to any `super()` constructor method is optional (or rather, when not present -- implicit), in the bytecode world it is always needed.

For black magic purposes I'm in need of knowing just by bytecode analysis and by the simplest method available, what's the `INVOKESPECIAL` call that corresponds to the Java world's `super()` call.

I'll leave you here with a hard example:

```
public static class A {
    public A(Object o, Object b) {
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
    public B() {
        //the below super is in bold just to signal that's the one
        //I'm looking for
        SUPER(new A(new Object(), new Integer(2)), new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(new A(new Object(), new Integer(2)));
    }
}
```

with the corresponding bytecode:
[image]

Comment: do you mean you want to see the constructor call chaining?

Comment: I need to know which invokespecial in the bytecode actually corresponds to the Java code super() call.

Comment: What if the constructor calls a different constructor in the same class? That's allowed in Java too.

Comment: The calls look ambiguous. But my guess is, the last one should be the `super()` you're looking for at `52`

Comment: I know. And that'd be other issue. One step at a time.

Comment: Aniket, the last one corresponds to the call to System.out.println()

Comment: at 52? No, its `invokespecial` not `invokevirtual`

Comment: It is when `A.<init>` is called on `this` or `aload_0` In this case the last one on byte 52.

Comment: @Aniket Constructors are never virtual.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am saying what you're saying. The last one on byte 52. I have mentioned `52` thrice before this.

Comment: Argh, the example is wrong. Just a sec.

Comment: @Aniket +1 for counting the `52` in the same message. ;)

Comment: Ok, corrected the example.

Comment: Now what we're aiming at is @31. Am I right?

Comment: Will the code given in the example even compile?

Comment: I assume `SUPER` should be `super`.  My answer is still the same. You have to determine which `A.<init>` is called on the value from `aload_0`

Comment: @Aniket Line 56 is when he creates a new A.

Comment: that's not the question :-| @Arham

Comment: @Aniket but without proper coding it's hard to reproduce the bytecode.:) Anyways, have a look at my answer below. it's line 31 which invokes super().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the rules for bytecode constructors are much more lax than Java's rules.

The only rule is that exactly one constructor must be called on any path that returns normally and if a constructor call throws an exception, then you must throw an exception too.

Among other things, this means that a constructor may contain multiple calls to other constructors or none at all.

Anyway, the only guaranteed way to determine whether a given `invokespecial` call is initializing the current object is to do a dataflow analysis, since it's possible to initialize other objects of the same class, which would confuse a naive detector.

Edit: Here is an example of a perfectly valid class (using the Krakatau assembler syntax), showing some of the issues you could run into. Among other things, it has calls to other constructors in the same class, recursive invocation of constructors, and constructing other objects of the same class inside the constructor.

```
.class public ctors
.super java/lang/Object

; A normal constructor
.method public <init> : ()V
    .limit locals 1
    .limit stack 1

    aload_0
    invokespecial java/lang/Object <init> ()V
    return
.end method

; A weird constructor
.method public <init> : (I)V
    .limit locals 2
    .limit stack 5

    iload_1
    ifne LREST
        aload_0
        invokespecial ctors <init> ()V
        return

LREST:
    aload_0
    new ctors
    iinc 1 -1
    iload_1
LFAKE_START:
    invokespecial ctors <init> (I)V
LFAKE_END:
    iconst_0
    invokespecial ctors <init> (I)V
    return

.catch [0] from LFAKE_START to LFAKE_END using LCATCH
LCATCH:
    aload_0
    invokespecial java/lang/Object <init> ()V
    return
.end method

.method public static main : ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit locals 1
    .limit stack 2

    new ctors
    iconst_5
    invokespecial ctors <init> (I)V
    return
.end method
```

Comment: Look at the example given above.

Comment: There are multiple invokespecials in the example

Comment: which is precisely the reason I'm asking on how to determine which one corresponds to the "super" call in the Java code..

Comment: So, just to make it clear. you are confirming my fears that there is no quick way of achieving my black magic purposes, without resorting to a full blown deep analysis, is that it?

Comment: @devoured I just posted an example of a class where dataflow analysis would be required and which has multiple subconstructor calls.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to count the number of `new A` object and the number of `A.<init>`  When there is more `init` than `new` you have called the super constructor. You have to do the same check for `new B` and `B.<init>` in case `this(...)` is called.

Comment: This may work for compiled Java code but it will fail on arbitrary bytecode for the reasons I outlined in my answer.

Comment: @Antimony I have tried arbitrary calls to the constructor or new without a constructor and they all got a VeritfyError in the JVM.

Comment: Did you try the class I posted? It runs just fine. I can post an assembled version somewhere if you want to try it without downloading my assembler.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find out at which invoke opcode the operand stack contains the `this` reference which will be used as the first argument. For this you just need to know about the effects on the operand stack that the different opcodes have. In your example you start with `aload_0` (which is the `this` reference), then do quite a bit of magic above that reference (updating the operand stack all the time). After a while the invoke opcode you are looking for is there, which consumes the `this` reference (and some references for the arguments). This then is the `super` call.

Comment: This will not work if the `this` reference is not that easy to identify, though. Very strange code might put put it into a static field and retrieve it using a getter-method again - this is hard to detect without proper static analysis, of course. So I guess you're best served with a solution that works for not-too-bad code.

Comment: @C actually that's not allowed. Uninitialized references have to stay within the function (or be passed to another constructor). However, you still need static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to super() invocation is line no. 31.

I found it easy via eclipse's Class File editor. 
Have a look at the snap attached below.

One thing to remember here is,
The prefix 'a' means that the opcode is manipulating an object reference. The prefix 'i' means the opcode is manipulating an integer.

So, the line by line explanation is as follows,

```
12  new java.lang.Integer //Create a new java.lang.Integer 
15  dup //Make a extra reference to the same Integer
16  iconst_2 // this means opcode is manipulating Integer as Integer(2)
17  invokespecial java.lang.Integer(int) //Integer(2) is invoked
20  invokespecial A(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) //new A(new Object(), new Integer(2) is invoked
23  new java.lang.Integer //Create a new java.lang.Integer
26  dup //Make a extra reference to the same Integer
27  iconst_1 // this means opcode is manipulating Integer as Integer(1)
28  invokespecial java.lang.Integer(int) //Integer(1) is invoked
31  invokespecial A(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) **//super(new A(new Object(), new Integer(2)), new Integer(1)) is invoked**
```

I hope the later is easy to comprehend. :)

```
56 - this invoke is for the sysout related A(object,object) invocation.
```

[image]